# How can I set an input mask property to a text filed of access database so that it will add leading zeros?

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

I have a table field of text data type. I want to set an input mask property so that it add leading zeros to make 12 digits number. say, Input: 1256
it will automatically converted as 000000001256

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use input mask .. use textbox and use format() function when store the text

```
Dim MyStr as String = format(val(txtNumber.Text),"000000000000")
```